# Pane does not fit into the window

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

I am in the process of creating my first JavaFX application. I use SceneBuilder to design the GUI. I am facing the following problem:

I have dragged a Pane inside the GridPane. The Pane seems to have to follow the constraints given by RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints. The problem is that these are not aligned with my pane:

[image: see here]

I did not expect this to be a big problem, but this results in a gap that is visible when I run my code:

[image: see here]

I am talking about the white-colored part in this figure - I want this to be blue. Also, I want to see the entire pane in my window.

I played around and tried to figure this out on my own, but I don't see what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your `FXML`.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to fix the issue is the following:

Inside the Inspector, open the Layout-entry for ColumConstraints. Change HGrow and HAlignment from INHERIT to ALWAYS and LEFT, respectively.

[image: see here]

But if anyone knows more about this, feel free to post a separate answer!